# How to best cache questions in PHP

Tags: php

I want to load 100 questions to the user  browser (About 100 user at once from a single server) and store the options selected by user to the browser until the user click on Final Submit.

The questions will be retrieved using ajax when user is still answering.

I have tried PHP session and retrieved with AJax but I have a feeling that it is not the bet approach.

Is session okay? Or should I tried something else

Comment: Look up `browser local storage`

Comment: Then read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: Try a wizard plugin. No need to store the results. Also, it allows to go back and fix the answers, if needed.

Comment: @Ismael Miguel, what do you mean by wizard plugin

Comment: A plugin in jQuery to transform a form element into a wizard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local storage is the best way. Since, you're saying 100 questions and then options for each of them. Local storage used to have a limit of 10 MB.But has changed a lot since then. I believe 100 MB is also possible. Although would not advise those kind of numbers in browser.

Please read this to understand how to operate Local storage.

http://tutorial.techaltum.com/local-and-session-storage.html

Comment: Local Storage doesn't have a limit (except old IE's equivalent that could only store up to 5MB). The "limit" is a setting defined by the user. Opera 12.15 and older had a limit of 5MB, expandable to 100MB.